# Missing action bar when embedding YouTube video in Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, youtube

I've embedded a YouTube video in my Flash using AS3 but it's not showing the youtube bar (the play/pause, full screen etc) buttons.

The video plays when clicked and it only has the YouTube logo on the bottom right - which when clicked takes you to youtube. Here's the code:

```
Security.allowDomain("www.youtube.com");


var videoPlayer:Object;

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
     loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoaderInit);
     loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3"));

function onLoaderInit(event:Event):void {
     addChild(loader);
     loader.content.addEventListener("onReady", onPlayerReady);
}


function onPlayerReady(event:Event):void {
     trace("Ready");
     videoPlayer = loader.content;
     videoPlayer.setSize(214, 142); 
     videoPlayer.cueVideoByUrl("www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO HERE", 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After I posted the question I found the answer. Sorry for wasting the time of whoever reads it:

I had it loading the chromeless player instead of the embedded one. Here is the solution:

```
Loading the chromeless player

If your application is using a chromeless player, use the following URL to load the player in your application:

http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3

Loading the embedded player

Use the following URL to load an embedded video player. In the URL, replace the string VIDEO_ID with the 11-character YouTube video ID that identifies the video that the player will show.

http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?version=3
```